# Can't uninstall emacs on Debian

Tags: debian

I want to purge emacs from debian in order to install the newer version from git but when I do `apt-get purge emacs` and then `emacs`it still runs. Any idea on how to get rid of emacs ?

Answer (score 3):

The Debian package `emacs` is a metapackage. [These are empty packages that only describe dependencies.](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.package-meta-information.en.html) As such, they don't actually contain any programs, just links to other packages to install. Further, removing a metapackage does not result in its dependencies being removed.

This feature allows package managers to use transitional metapackages to more-or-less gracefully move users from using one package to another with a different name.

So, removing the `emacs` package didn't actually remove any programs. That's why you needed to remove the rest of the emacs packages (`apt-get purge emacs*`) to get rid of emacs on your system.

[Regarding the `--purge` flag to apt-get](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.package-meta-information.en.html):

> When a Debian package is removed, the configuration files are retained in order to facilitate possible re-installation. Likewise, the data generated by a daemon (such as the content of an LDAP server directory, or the content of a database for an SQL server) are usually retained.
>
> To remove all data associated with a package, it is necessary to “purge” the package with the command, dpkg -P package, apt-get remove --purge package or aptitude purge package.

Thus, purge only removes system-installed config files (such as you might find in `/etc/` or `/var/`), not user-generated config (usually somewhere in `/home/<user>/`. It would be a very bad thing if the package manager erased user-generated files!

Answer (score -1):

`apt-get purge emacs*` did the trick even tho it didn't really purge the config files (̀`.emacs.d` still present...)

Comment: Purge deletes all the system-installed config. It shouldn't ever touch .emacs.d, that's where user config goes